# tortoiseSVN 1.8 upgrade did not upgrade svn.exe

Tags: svn

We have a Windows Server 2008 running IIS & Coldfusion where I recently upgraded TourtoiseSVN client from 1.7.4 to 1.8.2. The upgrade went ok with no errors. I rebooted the server for it to complete the Windows Explorer integration. `c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe` did not get upgraded. If I do `svn.exe --version` it says it is at version 1.7.4 while the GUI integration is at 1.8. I get an error when I use the command line svn.exe which says the client is too old to work with the working copy at ....

How can I get svn.exe upgraded to 1.8? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

You installed the optional (not installed by default) commandline tools with tortoise?  I'm guessing you have another commandline client installed (collabnet, cygwin, etc...) that is on your `%PATH%`.
Can you show us the output of these commands:

```
echo %PATH%

where svn

svn --version

C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe --version
```

Comment: That was the issue. Collabnet Subversion is installed on this server and it was in the PATH before TortoiseSVN.  Without fully qualifying the full path to svn.exe it used Collabnet svn. I changed PATH to include TortoiseSVN\bin 1st and I get the TortoiseSVN  1.8 version.   Thanks a bunch thekbb!

Comment: Glad to help.  Could you mark the answer as accepted for posterity?  It's helpful if this won't show up in a search for unanswered questions, and more importantly if someone finds it because they're having the same issue.