# After installing Tortoisesvn 1.8.2 command-promt still shows 1.7.6

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, working-copy

Installed 1.8.2 with command line client tools installed.

checked the version the the GUI and says. 1.8.2

when going into cmd -> svn --version
would show the version to be 1.7.6

not sure what to do at this point.

when I attempt to do svn upgrade at working copy it would say it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory along with E150000: Missing default entry

when I attempt to do svn log it would say E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy

Comment: this is likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985471/tortoisesvn-1-8-upgrade-did-not-upgrade-svn-exe/18987657#18987657,  I can't mark it as such because the answer isn't accepted.

Comment: From a command prompt, type `where svn.exe` and hit enter. What do you see as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. Did you reboot? Either that, or kill the task `explorer.exe` and restart it.

Take a look at your `%PATH%` via the `path` command. Where is `%PATH%` looking? There's no tool on Windows like `which` or `type` on Unix that will show you where the command is being executed, but take a look through the `%PATH%` anyway.

Go to the Control Panel through the Remove/Add Programs, and see what is installed. It is very possible that you have two versions of TortoiseSVN installed, or TortoiseSVN, and either the SlikSVN, Wandisco, VisualSVN, or CollabNet SVN command line client. You don't have to remove them, but you do need to adjust your `%PATH%` so that `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin` is first in your `%PATH%`.

Comment: thanks it was some other visualSVN that was installed on this computer without my knowledge that cause the problem